# What is a review task?

Tags: support

Forgive me my 'bad' question but I really do not understand what a [review](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/badges/102/custodian) task is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow the link, you can see the various review types, including reviewing edits, first posts etc for spelling, scope and so on.

https://security.stackexchange.com/review